# PL/SQL Record not stored in Database (not created)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following procedure for creating or defining a type as Record:

```
create or replace procedure p_two
as
type sample_record is RECORD
(
name varchar2(32),
age number,
emp_id varchar2 (32)
);

begin
  commit;
  dbms_output.put_line('Hello from procedure');
end p_two;
```

I just started working with PL/SQL and Oracle DB and trying all these on PL/SQL Developer and have the following code in SQL window for executing the procedure:

```
begin
   p_two;
   dbms_output.enable;
   dbms_output.put_line('Hello');
   commit;
end;
```

The issue is that the code runs successfully and I get the output `Hello` and `Hello from procedure` in the output tab but 'sample_record' is not stored in database or the record is not being created. It is not displayed under the `types` tab in PL/SQL Developer.

I tried the following directly in SQL window:

```
  create or replace  type sample_record is RECORD
    (
    name varchar2(32),
    age number,
    emp_id varchar2 (32)
    );
```

It compiles with error. But this time 'sample_record' is visible under `types` but it shows an error and does not show any attributes. I read a bit about it and came across some posts saying

> `Record is not supported by SQL schema and it is only supported in
>   PL/SQL`

which I assume is the reason why there's an error even though it's being displayed under types.

The doubt I have is how to create and a store a record type since doing it in a PL/SQL block is clearly not storing it and it is not directly supported by SQL schema so it compiles with an error.

I am new to these technologies since I mostly worked with MySQL but need to get familiar with PL/SQL and Oracle Db soon for a project. What I was attempting to do is create a procedure for inquiry. So I basically created an object `sample_object` and defined a table `sample_table` of type `sample_object` but I couldn't store values in the table directly. So I figured I will have to create a record and use it to populate the table created from the object. I still couldn't figure out the right way to do it and couldn't find any posts that uses objects and records to define tables and populate it. It would be nice if someone could share an article or tutorial on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no schema level `RECORD`. You may use the `OBJECT` keyword instead of `RECORD` to create a `TYPE`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  type sample_record IS OBJECT
 (
    name varchar2(32),
    age number,
    emp_id varchar2 (32)
);
```

You may also use a Package level record which may be used globally.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package pkg_objtest AS
TYPE sample_record IS RECORD (
    name varchar2(32),
    age number,
    emp_id varchar2 (32)
    );
END;
/


DECLARE
 srec pkg_objtest.sample_record;
BEGIN
   srec.name   := 'Mathews';
   srec.age    := 25;
   srec.emp_id := 'U203';
END;
/


Package PKG_OBJTEST compiled


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Why wouldn't the record appear under types? When I create an object or table it gets stored but records aren't getting stored.

Comment: @MathewsMathai : It may be a problem with your tool. Run `select * from all_objects where upper(object_name) = 'SAMPLE_RECORD';`, you'll find an entry.

Comment: I just noticed this record does get created but it is within the package and not global. So that query doesn't actually return anything. Is there any way to create records globally or do I always have to create them within package and a access using `package_name.record_name`?

Comment: @MathewsMathai : It's not possible to define a record globally.As I may have implied, `object` in a schema is analogous to a `record`.You should tell us clearly what you're trying to achieve. I believe I have answered the primary problem statement  in your question. You may consider accepting it if you think it helped. For further queries, I would suggest you to ask a separate question by **clearly** mentioning what you're trying to achieve ultimately and not a subset of the problem, which may not be needed at all.

Comment: I got the answer, Kaushik. Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Comment: Besides defining your record incorrectly there is another major issue why you see nothing n the database. There is no Insert statement. No insert statement then nothing will ever show up on the database. See [article working with records](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/working-with-records) and "SQL reference guide" for your Oracle version.